# Which unicode symbol can I use to symbolize a task needing feedback?

Tags: icons, feedback, symbols, user-communication

Unicode provides [check marks ✓](http://unicode-table.com/de/2713/)  and [ballot ✗](http://unicode-table.com/de/2717/) symbols that can be used to mark a task as having ended  with success or with an error.

I am wondering which icon, if any, could be used as for a task to require feedback.

As opposed to the [more general question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25016/what-symbol-to-use-to-represent-feedback) I am entirly looking for a unicode way.

Comment: Well, how about a question mark?

Comment: I'd say &#33; (!) would be self explanatory or a pencil meaning to "edit" or work on smth

Comment: Another quality question closed on Stack by anonymous coward "moderators" for a question about a literal non-commercial text standard.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the speech-balloon could work:

HTML Decimal: `&#128172;`

HTML HEx: `&#x1f4ac;`

Comment: Consider a quick check to ensure 'SPEECH BALLOON' is available in the font you intend to use.